# Create grouped checkbox lists in .net MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui

I'm using .NET MAUI and trying to create a set of checkbox lists that will be put inside a FlexLayout so that they will wrap.  When I hard code the data, it works fine.  Here's the working hard-coded solution:

```
<FlexLayout
    Grid.Row="5"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Direction="Row"
    Wrap="Wrap">                
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 1-1" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 1-2" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 1-3" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 1-4" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 2-1" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 2-2" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 2-3" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 2-4" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 3-1" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 3-2" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 3-3" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 3-4" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 4-1" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 4-2" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 4-3" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
            <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="Label 4-4" />
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

and the results, with a bit of wrapping looks like the following:

[image: Good Results]

I tried using the CollectionView grouping feature, but the one issue I would always run into was that the GroupedCheckboxLists ( the extension of the list) would cause my XAML error that the IsChecked and Label attributes were not found.  I tried all the solutions and never got it to work.

So now I'm trying nested CollectionViews and I can get results, but it shows all the checkboxes vertically and not side-by-side.  Here's my View Model:

```
public partial class CheckBoxViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string label;

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool isChecked;

    [ObservableProperty]
    int groupNumber;

    [ObservableProperty]
    int sortOrder;
}


public partial class CheckBoxGroupViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    string group;

    [ObservableProperty]
    List<CheckBoxViewModel> checkBoxes;

    public CheckBoxGroupViewModel(string name,  List<CheckBoxViewModel> checkBoxes)
    {
        this.group = name;
        this.checkBoxes = checkBoxes;
    }

}
```

and here's my XAML:

```
<FlexLayout
    Grid.Row="5"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Direction="Row"
    Wrap="Wrap">
    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectRooms}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Common.CheckBoxGroupViewModel">
                <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Common.CheckBoxViewModel">
                                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</FlexLayout>
```

This shows like the following:

[image: Bad Checks]

Any Ideas how to get it to show the groups side-by-side and wrap?

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying the solution below but the problem is that I want these to be in a FlexLayout so that it'll fit on any device, and wrap the Checkboxes within their Group.  Here's the update to a FlexLayout, but still getting all the VerticalLayouts in one column:

```
<FlexLayout
    Grid.Row="5"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Direction="Row"
    Wrap="Wrap">
    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectRooms}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout
                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="200">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</FlexLayout>
```

Comment: if your first solution works, why don't you just use that?  You can use a [Bindable Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-8.0) to avoid having to hardcode the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put `BindableLayout` inside of `CollectionView` to achieve this.

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this fucntion.

You can refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiInnerListApp0201.MainPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MauiInnerListApp0201.Models" >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:TestViewModel></vm:TestViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"
                        ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>

                    <Label Text="{Binding Group}" />
                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}"   Orientation="Vertical">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </VerticalStackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<CheckBoxGroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; } = new List<CheckBoxGroupViewModel>();

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        List<CheckBoxViewModel> Items1 = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();

        CheckBoxGroupViewModel group1;

        Items1.Add (new CheckBoxViewModel() {  GroupNumber = 1 ,  IsChecked= true, Id= "1", Label= "Label 1-1", SortOrder = 01});
        Items1.Add (new CheckBoxViewModel() {  GroupNumber = 1 ,  IsChecked= true, Id= "2", Label= "Label 1-1", SortOrder = 01});
        Items1.Add (new CheckBoxViewModel() {  GroupNumber = 1 ,  IsChecked= false, Id= "3", Label= "Label 1-1", SortOrder = 01});
        Items1.Add (new CheckBoxViewModel() {  GroupNumber = 1 ,  IsChecked= true, Id= "4", Label= "Label 1-1", SortOrder = 01});

        group1 = new CheckBoxGroupViewModel("group-1", Items1);

        List<CheckBoxViewModel> Items2 = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();
        CheckBoxGroupViewModel group2;

        Items2.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 2, IsChecked = true, Id = "1", Label = "Label 2-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items2.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 2, IsChecked = true, Id = "2", Label = "Label 2-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items2.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 2, IsChecked = false, Id = "3", Label = "Label 2-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items2.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 2, IsChecked = true, Id = "4", Label = "Label 2-1", SortOrder = 01 });

        group2 = new CheckBoxGroupViewModel("group-2", Items2);

        List<CheckBoxViewModel> Items3 = new List<CheckBoxViewModel>();
        CheckBoxGroupViewModel group3;

        Items3.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 3, IsChecked = true, Id = "1", Label = "Label 3-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items3.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 3, IsChecked = true, Id = "2", Label = "Label 3-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items3.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 3, IsChecked = false, Id = "3", Label = "Label 3-1", SortOrder = 01 });
        Items3.Add(new CheckBoxViewModel() { GroupNumber = 3, IsChecked = true, Id = "4", Label = "Label 3-1", SortOrder = 01 });

        group3 = new CheckBoxGroupViewModel("group-3", Items3);

        Groups.Add(group1);
        Groups.Add(group2);
        Groups.Add(group3);
    }
}
```

Note:

You can adjust the column number by `ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 3"`.

For more information, you can check: [Specify CollectionView layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0).

**Update:**

> So the main issue is that I want these Checkbox Groups in a FlexLayout
> as I do not know how many will actually be in the list and it'll be
> shown on different devices. I'd rather not set it to static 3 columns.

Please try the following code:

```
<FlexLayout
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"  Direction="Row" AlignContent="Start" AlignItems="Start"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"  JustifyContent="Start"
        Wrap="Wrap">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <VerticalStackLayout
                       BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}"  >
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                                    <Label Margin="5,15,0,0" Text="{Binding Label}" />
                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
```

Comment: I have one issue that I keep getting, and was getting when I tried to use the IsGrouped solution that has to do with Binding.  I'm trying to use your sample above, but on the {Binding Group} and {Binding Checkboxes} I get an error stating 'Member not found in data context 'TestViewModel'?  It seems when I'm binding my collection to my List, it isn't changing the datatype to the List item.

Comment: Ok...I figured that out...I removed the x:Datatype from the ContentPage definition.  So the main issue is that I want these Checkbox Groups in a FlexLayout as I do not know how many will actually be in the list and it'll be shown on different devices.  I'd rather not set it to static 3 columns.

Comment: Hi @MattS.,  please check the updated part of my answer at the bottom of my reply.  :)